# Calculating the best image size for a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

In my app I have table view cell that is sized at 600x300, and I want to put a background image in each cell that takes up the entire space. I thought I could just throw a 600x300px image into it and it would look fine but the images don't look the best.

So I was wondering how if there were some calculation I could use to find the best image resolution for a TableViewCell, that I could apply to my situation. Thanks!

P.s. I am building my app for the iPhone 6s and 6s Plus.

Here is a picture of the issue, notice how the picture of Hillary Clinton looks weird.

[image]

Comment: You can use cell.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit. As the aspect ratio of your image is 1:2 and the cell size ratio is also 1:2. It will show the image correctly.

Comment: Maybe upload a picture so we can see what exactly is wrong also :)

Comment: Check out my edited post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just set the **.ScaleAspectFill** property for your image could works.

You can do it in the Storyboard *(Attributes inspector, View -> Mode)* or by adding the following line :

```
imgView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

Hope that help you.